# Position panel in center of page with minimum left position using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to have a panel in the middle of the page but when I resize the page to smaller than the panel width, I want the panel to sit at x-pos of 0.  ie.  The panel will not push off the left of the screen when resized to less than the width of the panel.

For instance, the following code places the panel nicely in the middle but when the browser is resized to smaller than the widht of the panel, it shoves off the left side of the browser.

Is there any way of forcing the panel to stay at 0px left position in that case?

```
<div style="position:fixed; width:800px; top:0px; left:50%; margin-left:-400px;">
  content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a media query, f.e.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) { /* this has to be the same width as the div */
    div {
        margin-left:0;
        left:0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3zpm/

Comment: You should explain for the OP that it's a responsive technique and the `max-width` value have to be the same as the `width` of the div to works. Anyway +1

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown suggestion added

Answer (score 1):

I found this page with good example: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt#Fixed. Work for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin:auto; width:800px; top:0px;">
  content
</div>
```